# How to move console toolbar of debug and run tab of intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Anyone has idea about how to move the console toolbar of run tab of intelliJ IDEA?

[image: A representation about what I want to achieve]

I want to move it from right to left. I tried to restore layouts, etc, but without positive results.

Comment: This toolbar can not be moved and its location is specific to the JUnit console tab.

Comment: I always had it at left, why is now at right?

Comment: Looks like specific to JUnit. Feel free to report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that is due to JUnit?

Comment: The location of this toolbar is at the left for other tool windows. It was moved to the right because we discovered that users use it rarely and this tool bar "tears up"(obstruct) the other actions in tool bar. Do you really use it? Do you have an issue with current layout? (we can move the discussion to youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)

Comment: Yeah, I was using it a lot in order to clean the console hahaha. Probably I can get used to it, but I was caught unforeseen.